# Many to one relationship on a junction table (many to many) or a custom field type?

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, database-schema

Currently, I have two tables, `Exercise` and `WorkoutPlan`. These will have a many to many relationship.

```
Exercise
    - ID
    - Name
    ...

WorkoutPlan
    - ID
    - Name
    - Exercises (Many to Many with Exercise through WorkoutPlanExercise)
    ...
```

In this Many to Many relationship table, I need to store information about a number of `sets`,  such as there `min_rest`, `max_rest`, `min_repetitions` and `max_repetitions`.

Where I'm stuck is, is trying to figure out the best solution to do this. My **first solution** is to have another table (`WorkoutPlanExerciseSet`) that has a many to one relationship with the many to many table (`WorkoutPlanExercise`), as shown below.

```
WorkoutPlanExercise
    - ID
    - ExerciseID
    - WorkoutPlanID
    - Sets (One to Many with WorkoutPlanExerciseSet)

WorkoutPlanExerciseSet
    - WorkoutPlanExerciseID
    - MinRepititions
    - MaxRepititions
    - MinRest
    - MaxRest
```

My **second solution** is to store all the information about the exercise set, in a single row in the many to many relationship table (`WorkoutPlanExercise`). For example:

```
WorkoutPlanExercise
ID      ExerciseID      WorkoutPlanID       Sets        Repititions             Rest
1       1               1                   3           10-12, 10-10, 12-12     90-120, 60-90, 30-30
```

To note, both the rest time and number of repetitions, can be a range or a single number. For the second solution, I think I would create a custom Django Form Field.

Which is better? Is the former bad database design? Is the latter bad application design?

If it makes any difference, I wish to be able to easily display the information in a user friendly manner, such as:

```
Example Workout Plan
Exercise        Sets        Repetitions         Rest
Pull Ups        3           10 - 12             90 - 120
                            8 - 10              30
                            6 - 8               30
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess second. Read about custom `through` field [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).

UPDATE: see comments.

UPDATE 2, 3:

Actually, both are very nice. It depends on how you want to process data, stored in `Repetitions` and `Rest` fields. If you want to do heavy manipulations and calculations with data, e. g. calculate total rest time for WorkoutPlan or total number of repetitions for Exercise, then using former approach will be slightly easier.

UPDATE 4:

Storing data of the same kind as CSV in one field is bad idea. You will have a lot of fun if you have to change schema in the future. Use first approach. Also [link1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), [link2](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm).

Comment: Any reason why you would go with the second approach, as apposed to the first?

Comment: Sorry, your first solution is better.

Comment: Any chance you could provide me a reason why?